Where have the calendars in /usr/share/calendar/ gone?
In older versions of macOS, there used to be some Unix calendars in /usr/share/calendar/ like national calendars but also for pop culture related events (like LotR). I'm now on macOS Sonoma 14.5 and I can't find them anywhere (on my Apple Silicon MacBook Air). I've searched a bit but couldn't find any information on whether they been moved to a different location or whether they have been removed completely.
Where can I find a recent version of these files?

I can find a reddit post revealing their location on macOS 3 years ago; so I suspect they went missing from Monterey or Ventura onwards. Apple does seem to be stripping the Unix underpinnings to the bare minimum, so they've saved themselves 98Kb. ;-)
A quick check of my Time Machine backup from 2020 shows that there were 22 files in/usr/share/calendar/, defining various calendars; and 9 subfolders with additional calendars.
As well as national holidays, there were calendars of famous dates in history; births and death of musicians; and notable events in computing.
The calendars can be found here:
https://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:13:aarch64/latest/All/calendar-data-2022.11.pkg
This is not a Mac .pkg file, so won't work with Installer.app. To install, use an admin account and run
curl -s https://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:13:aarch64/latest/All/calendar-data-2022.11.pkg \
    | sudo tar xzf - -C / --exclude '*MANIFEST'

This will put the calendar files directly into /usr/local/share/calendar.
To use, run calendar -f calendar.all or similar.

They're still present in Ventura 13.6.7.

@MarcWilson They go missing from my backups in 2021, interestingly.

Check man calendar, the command expects a calendar file in the current directory, or in one of the paths listed in the FILES section. And you can use -f to name a different file. So, cd usr/local/share/calendar; calendar -A 42 -f calendar.computer works. Or you install the whole directory structure to /usr/local/share/calendar.

Running the command from my previous comment had me stumble over "Aug 14  First Unix-based mallet created, 1954" and lead me down a rabbit hole.

@nohillside Ah: I got my dirs and files and .calendars and calendars mixed up. Yes, I used to read all this stuff back in the 90s.
